# Подскажите сколько тип направление есть в php?

Tags: php

Подскажите сколько тип направление есть в php? Кроме

```
header('Location: news');
exit();
```

и

```
exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url= /index.php'>");
```

Comment: Это вообще не относится к PHP, это относится к HTML и HTTP. Подробнее в соответствующей документации.

Comment: @Etki, Аааа, я понял! я просто новичок спасибо вам!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то это часть протокола HTTP.
Он регулирует что есть в заголовках будет `Location`, то клиент должен запросить его значение.
А в PHP или HTML - просто варианты установки этого заголовка, во всех ЯП, которые имеют доступ к сетям, есть подобные возможности.

Comment: Спасибо вам у меня просто ajax формы и я затрудняюсь...

Comment: HTML не имеет отношения к заголовкам HTTP

Comment: @Etki, Чего придираешься? Я же сказал - ЯП, которые работают с сетью. HTML даже если и можно назвать ЯП (споры постоянно идут), то у него точно нет доступа к сети. К парсеру - да, к сети - неа, а значит заголовков нет.  
И если кое-то так дотошно придирается, то `meta refresh` - это просто указание браузеру, ОК?

Comment: @KYRAN, Да не за что.

Comment: "Чего придираешься?" -> "PHP или HTML - просто варианты установки этого заголовка"

Comment: @Etki, Ну не так выразился, тем более что дальше я как бы исправляют мысль, пойми и прости :)

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле существует всего два типа перенаправления (на самом деле - вообще один). Первый предусматривает перенаправление на уровне протокола (если грубо, то тот самый header location), второй - так или иначе заставить браузер выполнить переход. Второй крайне нежелателен по той причине, что на страницу будут заходить не только браузеры, но еще поисковики, боты пятнадцатилетних хакиров и Internet Wayback Machine, и в этом случае браузер будет просто отсутствовать.

Браузер (точнее сказать - клиент) и сервер общаются друг с другом по протоколу HTTP. Этот протокол позволяет передавать общую информацию о запросе (клиент передает адрес запрашиваемого ресурса, серевер отдает статус выполнения запроса), мета-информацию (дополнительные заголовки - время модификации, куки и пр.) и само тело запроса или ответа (тело ответа и является веб-страницей). Сервер **в обязательном порядке** отдает статус запроса - трехзначный код, характеризующий выполнение или невыполнение операции. Все статусы, начинающиеся с двойки означают успешное выполнение запроса, с тройки - перенаправление, с четверки - неправильный запрос, с пятерки - ошибку на сервере. В контексте этого вопроса интересуют статусы `3xx`, потому что именно они отвечают за перенаправление. Когда на сервере выполняется команда, аналогичная `header('Location: news');`, то PHP автоматом устанавливает статус ответа в `302` (если я правильно помню), и, таким образом, тот, кто получит ответ, однозначно будет уведомлен о перенаправлении, а ответ будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
302 Temporarily Moved
Location: news
```

(да-да, на самом деле в интернете все просто обмениваются кусками текста)

Клиент в этом случае прочитает 302, прочитает Location и перенаправится.

Все вышеописанно является частью протокола HTTP. Управление через `<meta>` в тексте документа и `window.location` в javascript является нежелательным из-за того, что не все клиенты читают содержимое ответа и не все клиенты его правильно интерпретируют (так, как хочется автору). Единственный и правильный safe-way - это использовать перенаправление через `header()` (возможно, кроме простого location есть еще другие заголовки с аналогичной функцией, но они наверняка предназначены для других целей), потому что иначе вас не поймут все небраузерные клиенты, и на Internet Wayback Machine в результате окажется страница, которая будет перенаправлять пользователя в никуда. Наверняка существует порядка десяти "браузерных" способов перекинуть пользователя, но использовать их - некорректно.

В качестве постскриптума: любые действия в PHP приведут к тому, что либо сформируется определенный HTTP-ответ, либо сформируется HTML-документ, в котором в том или ином виде браузеру будет рекомендовано совершить переход. PHP в этом случае реально не занимается ничем большим, чем формированием ответа; эти же операции мог бы проделать любой другой язык, а результатом работы является простой текстовый документ, который можно хоть руками в блокноте набить (но не стоит, конечно).

Comment: Вот что значит человеку не лень писать :)  
Другими словами либо может перенаправить сервер, дав команду `Location`, либо клиент (`meta refresh` или `location.href`), хотя это сложно назвать перенаправлением, т.к. это просто другой запрос, а не запрос, отклонённый в пользу другого ресурса.

Comment: @Etki, Спасибо Вам за Всё! Я узнал много нового!

Comment: Если вам не лень писать, можете ещё расписать, как менять HTTP коды из PHP (или хотя бы, что это имеет большой смысл делать). :)

Answer (score 1):

1. header() -> Location
2. Request-URI
3. Content-Location : http://example.com

также можно извратится при помощи JS

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";'; 
echo '</script>';
```